# "Definition Query on a versioned Geodatabase"

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, definition-query

I would like to implement Specific views to the SDE users,  based on Definition Queries of common attributes , like Date created > = October 1.

But on first look, the definition queries are for "feature Display setting" of each featureclass - Our aim is to implement it for the Feature dataset in a particular version

The below article did not help, as I could not locate , choose Production Cartography In the Categories list.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0103000000s5000000

What is the procedure to display features on a common attribute, across the feature dataset in a Version.

Comment: I believe Production Mapping is an extension that requires its own separate license (not sure if it's included in ELA's). If you have already purchased and installed it, it may need to be turned on. Go to the "Customize" menu and select "Extensions." We don't use it, so I'm not sure if it will do what you are talking about.

Comment: @msayler - So with out this extension, I guess there is no way to apply Definition Queries on a full dataset

Comment: There still might be other options to accomplish what you need. I'm not entirely convinced that extension would do what you want anyway. Can you expand on what the need is? Are you setting up maps for viewing? Or are you talking about viewing the tables themselves with some kind of filter applied? View-only or does the data need to be editable?

Comment: Our default dataset contains utility jobs from the last two years..We would like to make a view for the Quality control, only the features (jobs) which are created in the past month..Then the Quality control staff would be able to edit the current months data , that was the idea

Comment: I happen to work for an electric utility. I think we probably are using a different model though (we use ArcFM). Are you using some standardized MXDs for the maps? My first thought is to use arcpy to apply a definition query to the layers. To make things easier you could either set up a script to run on a schedule or set up an add-in tool for the users. You can't really do it at the database level that I know of, at least not really safely (probably could do it in the RDBMS directly, but SDE might not like that).